# SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ())

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, uglifyjs

I'm recieving:

**SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ())** from UglifyJS

and it points to the first letter of global variable `API_URL`.
I have it implemented in this way:

```
export default reduxApi({
  campaigns: {
    url: `${API_URL}/api/v1/whatever`,
    transformer (response) {
      if (!response) return {}
      return response.data
    }
  } 
}).use('fetch', adapterFetch(fetch)).use('options', {
  headers: getRequestHeaders()
})
```

If I remove global variable under key `url`:

```
export default reduxApi({
  campaigns: {
    url: `/api/v1/whatever`,
    transformer (response) {
      if (!response) return {}
      return response.data
    }
  } 
}).use('fetch', adapterFetch(fetch)).use('options', {
  headers: getRequestHeaders()
})
```

then everything works fine. Any ideas? Why uglify throws that kind of error?

Comment: What do you mean by `url`, do you mean `${API_URL}`?

Comment: @rckrd Edited. Now it should be understandable.

Comment: Thanks.  How to you set  `${API_URL}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to write here a solution. I didn't have to install other `uglify-js` package versions. The point was to solve imports to objects in proper way. In my case the `API_URL` was a global variable. So Uglify wasn't sure if it's defined, that's why it threw an error.

To solve that problem I used [webpack externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) in this way:

```
// ------------------------------------                                                                                               
// Externals
// ------------------------------------
webpackConfig.externals = {
  config: JSON.stringify(require(`./${__DEV__ ? 'development' : 'production'}.json`)),                                                
}
```

It just puts JSON configuration object into the `config` variable, depending on environment (`development` or `production`). All you need to do is to put `development.json` and `production.json` next to file where you define `webpackConfig.externals`.

Then as in my case, you define it let's say in `development.json`:

```
{
  "apiUrl": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

then finally in your code:

```
... // other imports
import config from "config"

export default reduxApi({
  campaigns: {
    url: `${config.apiUrl}/api/v1/whatever`,
    transformer (response) {
      if (!response) return {}
      return response.data
    }
  } 
}).use('fetch', adapterFetch(fetch)).use('options', {
  headers: getRequestHeaders()
})
```

and it works like a charm.

Hope that helps somebody.

Answer (score 3):

Uglify doesn't fully support ES6, [template literals included](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/448#issuecomment-282536895). You can [track the conversation on Github](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/448). There's a [`harmony` branch](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/tree/harmony) for ES6 support. You can use the branch by replacing your `package.json` entry for uglify to:

```
"uglify-js": "git+https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2.git#harmony"
```

Alternatively, you might want to pass the code through a transpiler first before minification. That way, all the syntax will be ES5 which Uglify understands very well. You might want to tweak your transpiler config if you want some of the ES6 syntax to remain intact.

Comment: I used your tip, I added this to my package.json, but I think there's something more to do with, because I'm using https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit and using your suggestion it doesn't work. Maybe some other dependencies?