# Laravel mix SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ())

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-mix

I am trying to use laravel mix to compile and minify files, if I run npm run dev everything works fine however running npm run production give me this:

```
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'production' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.3
3 info using node@v6.7.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preproduction', 'production', 'postproduction' ]
5 info lifecycle @~preproduction: @
6 silly lifecycle @~preproduction: no script for preproduction, continuing
7 info lifecycle @~production: @
8 verbose lifecycle @~production: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle @~production: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\cmder\bin;C:\Program Files\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\Scripts;C:\Program Files\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5;C:\Program Files\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu;C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState Komodo IDE 10\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;c:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;c:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Users\pwojt\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\pwojt\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\share\vim\vim74;C:\Program Files\cmder\
10 verbose lifecycle @~production: CWD: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel
11 silly lifecycle @~production: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
11 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js' ]
12 silly lifecycle @~production: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle @~production: Failed to exec production script
14 verbose stack Error: @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:242:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid @
16 verbose cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel
17 error Windows_NT 10.0.15063
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "production"
19 error node v6.7.0
20 error npm  v3.10.3
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ production script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I don't know what any of that means actually so I just posted it all, my webpack file looks like this:

```
mix.styles([
    'resources/assets/css/bootstrap-social.css',
    'resources/assets/css/bootstrap.css',
    'resources/assets/css/dropzone.css',
    'resources/assets/css/jquery-ui.css',
    'resources/assets/css/jquery-ui.structure.css',
    'resources/assets/css/jquery-ui.theme.css',
    'resources/assets/css/nav.css'
],  'public/css/style.css');
mix.scripts([
    'resources/assets/js/pace.js',
    'resources/assets/js/jquery.js',
    'resources/assets/js/page-load.js',
    'resources/assets/js/search.js',
    'resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js',
    'resources/assets/js/dropzone.js',
    'resources/assets/js/homesearch.js',
    'resources/assets/js/image-upload.js',
    'resources/assets/js/jquery-ui.js',
    'resources/assets/js/googlemap.js',
],  'public/js/script.js');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162237/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-punc)

Comment: i am not using UglifyJS i am using laravel mix so how is this duplicate?

Comment: Laravel mix uses Webpack and Webpack uses UglifyJS

Comment: anyway that topic does not solve my problem