# Gulp-uglify - Uglify function throwing errors

Tags: gulp, browserify, gulp-uglify

I'm attempting to uglify some javascript files using "gulp-uglify": "3.0.0" but keep getting error messages. I am also using browserify prior to bundling these files.

Code in gulp file:

```
var b = browserify({
entries: file,
debug: true
});

return b.bundle()
.pipe(source(file))
.pipe(buffer())
.pipe(uglify().on('error', function (e) {
console.log(e);
}))
.pipe(rename(file.replace(/^Views/, '')))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
```

Errors thrown in the task runner console output:

```
{ [GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript]
cause: 
   { [SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ())]
     message: 'Unexpected token: punc ())',
     filename: 'Views\\AccountDetails\\ContactDetails.js',
     line: 1547,
     col: 25,
     pos: 50851 },
  plugin: 'gulp-uglify',
  fileName: 'C:\\_src\\RETIG\\My.TONIKSpace\\My.TonikSpace\\Views\\AccountDetails\\ContactDetails.js',
  showStack: false }
{ [GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript]
  cause: 
   { [SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ())]
     message: 'Unexpected token: punc ())',
     filename: 'Views\\AccountDetails\\DirectDebitDetails.js',
     line: 73,
     col: 3,
     pos: 2086 },
  plugin: 'gulp-uglify',
  fileName: 'C:\\_src\\RETIG\\My.TONIKSpace\\My.TonikSpace\\Views\\AccountDetails\\DirectDebitDetails.js',
  showStack: false }
{ [GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript]
  cause: 
   { [SyntaxError: Unexpected character '`']
     message: 'Unexpected character \'`\'',
     filename: 'Views\\Usage\\Index.js',
     line: 157,
     col: 11,
     pos: 4109 },
  plugin: 'gulp-uglify',
  fileName: 'C:\\_src\\RETIG\\My.TONIKSpace\\My.TonikSpace\\Views\\Usage\\Index.js',
  showStack: false }
{ [GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript]
  cause: 
Process terminated with code 0.
   { [SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ())]
     message: 'Unexpected token: punc ())',
     filename: 'Views\\SharedAccounts\\Index.js',
     line: 183,
     col: 4,
     pos: 5991 },
  plugin: 'gulp-uglify',
  fileName: 'C:\\_src\\RETIG\\My.TONIKSpace\\My.TonikSpace\\Views\\SharedAccounts\\Index.js',
  showStack: false }
{ [GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript]
  cause: 
   { [SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ())]
     message: 'Unexpected token: punc ())',
     filename: 'Views\\AccountDetails\\Index.js',
     line: 1547,
     col: 25,
     pos: 50851 },
  plugin: 'gulp-uglify',
  fileName: 'C:\\_src\\RETIG\\My.TONIKSpace\\My.TonikSpace\\Views\\AccountDetails\\Index.js',
  showStack: false }
</code>
```

I have attempted to resolve these errors by changing the punctuation that the errors are referring too, but this doesn't feel right. Why isn't gulp just uglifying the files regardless of whether I'm using single or double quotes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162237/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-punc)

Comment: It looks like you are using ES6 with an uglify version that doesn't support ES6. See the duplicate link.