# Unexpected token: punc (:) [mathjax/es5/sre/mathmaps/de.js:2,19] after Upgrade to Angular12

Tags: angular, mathjax, angular12

I have upgraded my Angular app to version 12. Everything works except for mathjax. On running `ng serve` I receive below error

```
Error: mathjax/es5/sre/mathmaps/de.js from Terser
Unexpected token: punc (:) [mathjax/es5/sre/mathmaps/de.js:2,19]
    at js_error (c:\path\to\pro1ject\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:550:11)
    at croak (c:\path\to\pro1ject\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1274:9)
    at token_error (c:\path\to\pro1ject\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1282:9)
    at unexpected (c:\path\to\pro1ject\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1288:9)
    at semicolon (c:\path\to\pro1ject\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1326:56)
    at simple_statement (c:\path\to\pro1jectnode_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1583:73)
    at statement (c:\path\to\pro1ject\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1369:47)
    at _embed_tokens_wrapper (c:\path\to\pro1ject\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1339:26)
    at block_ (c:\path\to\pro1ject\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:2172:20)
    at statement (c:\path\to\pro1ject\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1403:29)
```

Several questions like [SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162237/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-punc) indicate that there is an invalid character in the package file.
Below is the mathjax/es5/sre/mathmaps/de.js:2,19

```
{
"fr/si/prefixes.js":  <--Error Occurs Here
[{"Y":"yotta","Z":"zetta","E":"exa","P":"péta","T":"téra","G":"giga","M":"méga","k":"kilo","h":"hecto","da":"déca","d":"déci","c":"centi","m":"milli","µ":"micro","μ":"micro","n":"nano","p":"pico","f":"femto","a":"atto","z":"zepto","y":"yocto"}]
,
"fr/functions/algebra.js": 
[{"locale":"fr"},{"category":"Algebra","mappings":{"default":{"default":"degré"}},"key":"deg","names":["deg"]},{"category":"Algebra","mappings":{"default":{"default":"déterminant"}},"key":"det","names":["det"]},{"category":"Algebra","mappings":{"default":{"default":"dimension"}},"key":"dim","names":["dim"]},{"category":"Algebra","mappings":{"default":{"default":"homomorphisme"}},"key":"hom","names":["hom","Hom"]},{"category":"Algebra","mappings":{"default":{"default":"noyau"}},"key":"ker","names":["ker"]},{"category":"Algebra","mappings":{"default":{"default":"trace"}},"key":"Tr","names":["Tr","tr"]}]
,
"fr/functions/elementary.js": 
[{"locale":"fr"},{"key":"log","mappings":{"default":{"default":"log"}},"category":"Logarithm","names":["log"]},{"key":"ln","mappings":{"default":{"default":"logarithme népérien"}},"category":"Logarithm","names":["ln"]},{"key":"lg","names":["lg"],"mappings":{"default":{"default":"logarithme décimal"}},"category":"Logarithm"},{"key":"exp","names":["exp","expt"],"mappings":{"default":{"default":"exponentielle"}},"category":"Elementary"},{"key":"gcd","names":["gcd","PGCD","pgcd"],"mappings":{"default":{"default":"plus grand commun diviseur"},"mathspeak":{"default":"pgcd"},"clearspeak":{"default":"pgcd"}},"category":"Elementary"},{"key":"lcm","names":["lcm","ppcm","PPCM","PPMC","ppmc"],"mappings":{"default":{"default":"plus petit commun multiple"},"mathspeak":{"default":"ppcm"},"clearspeak":{"default":"ppcm"}},"category":"Elementary"},{"key":"arg","names":["arg"],"mappings":{"default":{"default":"argument"}},"category":"Complex"},{"key":"im","names":["im"],"mappings":{"default":{"default":"partie imaginaire"}},"category":"Complex"},{"key":"re","names":["re"],"mappings":{"default":{"default":"partie réelle"}},"category":"Complex"},{"key":"inf","names":["inf"],"mappings":{"default":{"default":"borne inférieure"}},"category":"Limits"},{"key":"lim","mappings":{"default":{"default":"limite"}},"category":"Limits","names":["lim"]},{"key":"max","names":["max"],"mappings":{"default":{"default":"maximum"}},"category":"Limits"},{"key":"min","names":["min"],"mappings":{"default":{"default":"minimum"}},"category":"Limits"},{"key":"sup","names":["sup"],"mappings":{"default":{"default":"borne supérieure"}},"category":"Limits"},{"key":"lim inf","names":["lim inf","liminf"],"mappings":{"default":{"default":"limite inferior"}},"category":"Limits"},{"key":"lim sup","names":["lim sup","limsup"],"mappings":{"default":{"default":"limite superior"}},"category":"Limits"},{"key":"injlim","names":["injlim","inj lim"],"mappings":{"default":{"default":"limite inductive"}},"category":"Limits"},{"key":"projlim","names":["projlim","proj lim"],"mappings":{"default":{"default":"limite projective"}},"category":"Limits"},{"key":"mod","names":["mod"],"mappings":{"default":{"default":"modulo"}},"category":"Elementary"},{"key":"Pr","names":["Pr"],"mappings":{"default":{"default":"probabilité"}},"category":"Probability"}]
,
"fr/functions/hyperbolic.js": 
[{"locale":"fr"},{"key":"cosh","mappings":{"default":{"default":"cosinus hyperbolique"}},"category":"Hyperbolic","names":["cosh"]},{"key":"coth","mappings":{"default":{"default":"cotangente hyperbolique"}},"category":"Hyperbolic","names":["coth"]},{"key":"csch","mappings":{"default":{"default":"cosécante hyperbolique"}},"category":"Hyperbolic","names":["csch"]},{"key":"sech","mappings":{"default":{"default":"sécante hyperbolique"}},"category":"Hyperbolic","names":["sech"]},{"key":"sinh","mappings":{"default":{"default":"sinus hyperbolique"}},"category":"Hyperbolic","names":["sinh"]},{"key":"tanh","mappings":{"default":{"default":"tangente hyperbolique"}},"category":"Hyperbolic","names":["tanh"]},{"category":"Area","mappings":{"default":{"default":"argument cosinus hyperbolique"}},"key":"arcosh","names":["arcosh","arccosh","argch"]},{"category":"Area","mappings":{"default":{"default":"argument cotangente hyperbolique"}},"key":"arcoth","names":["arcoth","arccoth","argcoth"]},{"category":"Area","mappings":{"default":{"default":"argument cosécante hyperbolique"}},"key":"arcsch","names":["arcsch","arccsch","argcsch"]},{"category":"Area","mappings":{"default":{"default":"argument sécante hyperbolique"}},"key":"arsech","names":["arsech","arcsech","argsech"]},{"category":"Area","mappings":{"default":{"default":"argument sinus hyperbolique"}},"key":"arsinh","names":["arsinh","arcsinh","argsh"]},{"category":"Area","mappings":{"default":{"default":"argument tangente hyperbolique"}},"key":"artanh","names":["artanh","arctanh","argth"]}]
,

...

}
```

How do I resolve this error? Changing the file may not be a viable solution as there are about 130 lines from 6 different files on which this error occurs.

The build was successfully working in Angular 11

Below is my `eslint` config file

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2015
  },

  "env": {
    "es6": true
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json",
          "e2e/tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat--formatting-add-on",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": [
          "off",
          {
            "accessibility": "explicit"
          }
        ],
        "arrow-parens": [
          "off",
          "always"
        ],
        "import/order": "off"
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is an ESLint issue. It is most likely a TypeScript transpiling issue. Are you on version 3.1.4 of `mathjax`? It was released 24 days ago and I am thinking upgrading to this version in `package.json` may fix it.

Comment: @AliF50 I am using "mathjax": "^3.1.4", "@types/mathjax": "^0.0.36", "@dimakorotkov/tinymce-mathjax": "^1.0.7",