# I am getting issue in installing highchart 11.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I have tried to install highchart with npm in rails 6 and directly with its cdn link
I am continuously getting an error

```
Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token: punc (.)
```

Comment: This error is not related to Highcharts itself, rather to ES6. Have you tried to check similar topic on SO, like f.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162237/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-punc or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375468/uglify-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-punc etc.?